# Convert inline query to a query in TypeORM

Tags: sql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I need to convert this SQL query:

```
DECLARE @user AS dsschema.user_tools; 
INSERT INTO @user VALUES('`+ body.user_id+`','`+ body.tool_id+`'); 
EXECUTE dsschema.sp_user_tool @user
```

To a TypeORM `createQueryBuilder();`

Can someone please help me?

I tried the following but facing issues like:

`Must declare the scalar variable @user:`

**Service.ts**

```
class UserTools{
constructor(@InjectRepository(User) private userRepo: Repository:<User>)

 async insertUserData(body){
  try {
     const result = await this.manager.query(`DECLARE @user AS dsschema.user_tools`);
     const querybuilderResult = await this.userRepo.createQueryBuilder()
       .insert().into(@user).values({user_id: body.user_id, tool_id: body.tool_id});
     const spResult = await this.manager.query(`dsschema.sp_user_tool @user`);
     return spResult;
  } catch
  {
    throw error;
   }
 }
}
```

**user.entity.ts**

```
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class User {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    user_id: string;

    @Column()
    tool_id: string;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()` by default uses auto incrementing integers, meaning in your case `user_id` would be of type `number`, not `string`. You can find more information on the decorator in the [TypeORM Docs](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/entities.md#primary-columns):

> `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()` creates a primary column which value will be automatically generated with an auto-increment value. It will create `int` column with `auto-increment`/`serial`/`sequence`/`identity` (depend on the database and configuration provided).

Apart from that:

1. In your attempt you're executing the 3 instructions individually, meaning that the `@user` context is no longer available when you run your insert statement.
2. The table name is quoted by TypeORM, meaning it will try to insert to `"@user"` instead of `@user`. SQL server will reject this with `Invalid object name '@user'`.

Here's how you could do it:

```js
// This is the variable where the
// user_tools table will be stored
const userVariable = '@user';

// getQueryAndParameters() returns an array with
// two items, the query and the parameters.
//
// In this case:
// [
//   'INSERT INTO "@user"("user_id", "tool_id") VALUES (@0, @1)',
//   [ 123, 'abc' ]
// ]
//
const insertStatement = this.userRepo
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .insert()
  .into(userVariable)
  .values({
    user_id: 123,
    tool_id: 'abc',
  })
  .getQueryAndParameters();

// Here we execute the statements in the same batch
// to address [1]
// For [2] we have to unescape your variable 
// name @user (which is currently the quoted "@user") 
await this.userRepo.query(
  `
  DECLARE ${userVariable} AS dsschema.user_tools;
  ${insertStatement[0].replace(`"${userVariable}"`, userVariable)};
  EXECUTE dsschema.sp_user_tool ${userVariable};
  `,
  insertStatement[1]
);
```